# Accessing the Google Earth Pro image dataset for exporting a GeoTIFF

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, google-earth

I would like to extract with Earth Engine, Google Earth Pro GeoTIFF images in UTM projection using opposing corner coordinates.  In Google Earth Pro, the ~6” imagery I assume to be already processed raw satellite imagery that it is now in an `ImageCollection`. Can this `ImageCollection` be accessed directly where opposing corners are provided in the earth engine coder and then exported as a GeoTIFF? What would be the name of the `ImageCollection`?  Is there example code for doing this?

Is there example code for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I now have an alternative to Earth Engine. I found that USGS EarthExplorer UI and their high-resolution-orthoimagery meet my resolution needs and is fairly easy to use (no script required) in comparison to Google Earth Engine that is designed for higher level analysis work.